# Переход строки во время цикла

Tags: c++, строки, циклы, динамические-массивы

Я пишу код, который будет получать на вход число строк (n), сами строки, s[n], после чего создается массив, в котором будет только один пробел МЕЖДУ слов в строке. Изначально строки содержат пробелы между словами и по краям в случайном количистве. Во время цикла, почему-то считывание строк происходит так:

```
(n = 2)
S[0]=
S[1]= t ee x t
```

Хотя должно начинаться с первой строки. Пробовал считывать через `cin>>t`. После первой строки программа завершается. Как пофиксить?

```
getline(cin, t)
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "regex"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, i;
    cout<<"n=";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<endl;
    string s[n], t;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout<<"S["<<i<<"]= ";
        getline(cin, t);
        t = regex_replace(t, regex("^ +"), "");  // удаление начальных пробелов
        t = regex_replace(t, regex(" +$"), "");  // удаление конечных пробелов
        s[i] = t;
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вам надо прочесть остаток строки (с символом '\n') сразу после `cin>>n;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед циклом надо добавить строчку `cin.ignore(1, '\n');`

```
...
cin>>n;
cout<<endl;
string s[n], t;
cin.ignore(1, '\n');
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{...}
return 0;
```

Вводя строку, как только нажимаем enter, мы вводим символ переноса строки `\n`
Но `cin>>n`  считывает только до символа `\n`. И этот `\n` остается в сin. Поэтому когда в   следующий раз делаем считывание  getline(cin,t), первым символом считывается этот '\n'.

Используя `cin.ignore(1, '\n')` до функции `getline(cin, t)`  мы игнорируем этот `\n`. Мы не извлекаем, не выводим, не стираем этот `\n`, а просто пропускаем его.

В функции `cin.ignore(num, ch)` , 1ым аргументом  количество игнорирумых символов, 2ым аргументом символ-разделитель. Игноририрование остановится, либо когда будет проигнорировано num символов. Либо когда встретится символ-разделитель ch. Либо когда дойдём до `EOF`.